# How to force focus to a panel input. Firefox addon sdk

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm running into an issue where if a focus even is fired of by javascript on the current window's page it steals focus from my addons input. Is there a way to force an input in a panel to stay focused.

```
    $(inputSelector).focusout(function(){
        $(inputSelector).focus();
    }); 

    $(inputSelector).blur(function(){
        $(inputSelector).focus();
    });
```

I have tried the above which seems to work on my test page but not in my panel :(.

According to the docs -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel
Setting focus to false should

> Set to false to prevent taking the focus away when the panel is shown. 
>   Only turn this off if necessary, to prevent accessibility issue. 
>   Optional, default to true.

I have set my panel up as such.

```
    var text_entry = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
        width: text_entry_width,
        height: text_entry_h,
        focus: false, // doesnt seem to work....

        contentURL: data.url("entry.html"),

        contentScriptFile: [
            data.url("jquery-2.1.1.min.js"),
            data.url("text.js")
        ],

        contentStyleFile: [
            data.url("styles.css")
        ]
    });
```

It doesn't append that setting it to false works :(.

Any help, guidance or comments would be awesome :) Cheers.

_____________ UPDATE ____________________________________________

There seemed to be some confusion of my bad explaining :( so i have uploaded a video to youtube that will hopefully explain the issue a bit better.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fhJzpa515Y&feature=youtu.be

Also below find some more code.

**Panel Html**

```
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <div id="resultTableTop" class="resultTable"></div>
            <input type="text" id="edit-box"></input>
            <div id="resultTableBottom" class="resultTable"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Hot Key Code**

```
    var showHotKey = Hotkey({
        combo: "accel-t",
        onPress: function() {
            text_entry.show();
        }
    });
```

**Panel js show listenter**

```
    self.port.on("show", function onShow() {
        $('input').focus();
        console.log('hi');
    });
```

Hopefully this is a bit clearer now :) thanks for the help so far :).

Comment: `Panel` is non modal by design. You can't, and you shouldn't, force the user to interact with it.

Comment: That seems a bit silly, im halfway through typing into my text box and some java script niks the focus. I would have been under the impression that you could at least do something hacky along the lines of my jquery code. The goal is not to force the user but when the user has chosen to interact with the input i would expect to be able to keep the focus on the input.

Comment: You mean a web page script steals the focus from your panel?

Comment: You can do it, with addon-sdk its hacky, with non addons-sdk its not hacky. But yeah answer paas q plz.

Comment: Yes during testing in the sdk when the home page opens with the search bar if i have my addon focused the search bar steals the focus(from the web page).

Answer (score 0):

This code focuses panel's input field when it opens:

main.js file:

```
//main.js file
var text_entry = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    focus: true, //THIS SHOULD BE TRUE
    contentURL: data.url("panel.html"),
    contentScriptFile: [
        data.url("js/libs/jquery-1.11.1.js"),
        data.url("get-text.js")
    ]
});

text_entry.on("show", function() {
    text_entry.port.emit("show");
});
```

get-text.js file which is injected into panel:

```
//data/get-text.js file
self.port.on("show", function onShow() {
    $('input').focus();
});
```

Comment: I currently use that already sorry i should have included it. The problem is not getting focus when the panel launches it is keeping it. Essentially I open the panel during page load i get focus start typing. On page ready fires off on the windows javascript and somewhere in there it calls a focus. I want to prevent the main firefox window taking focus when my panel is active.

Comment: Also changing focus from true to false doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I have tested this and it does not maintain focus. I will record a video i think an put it up. maybe its a bug :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hacky, untested, solution:

```
var { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core");
var { Panel } = require("sdk/panel");


var panel = Panel({
  ..
  onShow: function() {
    var view = viewFor(panel);
    view.setAttribute("noautohide", "true");
  }
})
```

[For more information of the panel noautohide attribute click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/panel#a-panel.noautohide).

Comment: Thanks for the answer i will try implementing it when i get home tonight.

Comment: This only prevents the window from fading away when focus is lost if doesnt prevent the focus issue in the first place :(

Comment: `require("sdk/view/core").getActiveView(panel)` will work to get the XUL element

Comment: this technique seems to make the panel model, but then not possible to close. I think what is required is a modal panel that is only open and closed using the toolbar toggle button and not closed by losing focus